# Delete Duplicates for Large Dataset, Both True Duplicates (Whole row is duplicate) and Duplicate Based on One Column

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a rather large dataset. Minimum rows are in the 8K range. I need to delete duplicates on two conditions. The first would be what I call a "True Duplicate." By definition this means that the entire row is a duplicate. Here is the script I have that works for that scenario.

```
function removeDuplicates(sheet) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  var trueDuplicateCount = 0;

  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {//Look for duplicates across all rows. True Duplicate
        duplicate = true;
        trueDuplicateCount = trueDuplicateCount + 1;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  return trueDuplicateCount;
}
```

The other condition would be a duplicate based on one column's info. After having removed "True Duplicates" I need to delete duplicates based on a column. I would like to keep the line with the earliest date on another column.

**Here is what I tried but does not work for this scenario.**

```
function removeDuplicates(sheet) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  var trueDuplicateCount = 0;
  var diffDateDuplicateCount = 0;

  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {//Look for duplicates across all rows. True Duplicate
        duplicate = true;
        trueDuplicateCount = trueDuplicateCount + 1;
      }
      if(row[1] == newData[j][1] && row[0] > newData[j][0]){
        duplicate = true;
        diffDateDuplicateCount = diffDateDuplicateCount + 1
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  return [trueDuplicateCount, diffDateDuplicateCount];
}
```

**Here is a sample of the dataset**

[image]

**After Deleting the "True Duplicates"**

[image]

**After Deleting the duplicate with the later date**

[image]

The above is what would be left after the script ran and then the function would also return an array with the count for each type of duplicate deleted.

The current script works for the True Duplicates portion, but I'm concerned about speed and possibly timing out on a larger dataset. With 8K rows I'm already seeing almost 3 minute run time. With that said, here are my asks.

**Conditions**

- Speed, speed, speed. Is there a more efficient way of handling this? **This is my biggest concern.**
- Must remove duplicate with the later date and keep the one with the earliest date.
- Must return a count for each type of duplicate removed.

Hoping this clears up some confusion. I've shown what I want done with each step. (Acct Number is made up)

[image]

**Comment about Solution chosen**

I went with the solution that executed the fastest. While both Tanaike's and Master's worked, I went with Master's because I anticipate a lot of lines in the future. Every millisecond counts.

I just want to thank those who answered especially Tanaike who put in a lot of work. Hopefully this question becomes the holy grail for deleting duplicates because your non-v8 solution is still great for those without v8.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. About `Must remove duplicate with the later date and keep the one with the earliest date.`, in your sample values, there are 2 values of `01/23/2020,orange`. In this case, which value do you want to remove? 2. About `Must return a count for each type of duplicate removed.`, when your sample values in your question are used, what values do you expect?

Comment: There are 3 Orange. two with date 01/23 and one with date 01/22. First, one of the two 01/23 rows are deleted. Then on the second condition only the 01/22 survives. As for the counts.. I should see True Duplicates = 2 and Diff Date Duplicates = 3.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the logic for retrieving `True Duplicates = 2 and Diff Date Duplicates = 3` from your sample values. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: A true duplicate means the whole row is the same as another. In that case delete one. After all of the true duplicates have been deleted then we do a check on duplicates of one column and delete the one with the later date. So using the orange example... there are two with 01/23 and one with 01/22. First delete one 01/23, then delete the other 01/23 because 01/22 is the earlier date and we want to keep that one.

Comment: Using a different example. Orange, 01/20... Orange, 01/21... Orange, 01/23... Orange 01/23. First delete the true duplicate (01/23). Then delete the older duplicates. (01/21 and 01/23)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm whether my understanding for your logic is correct. About `True Duplicates = 2`, the difference between the number of data of `Here is a sample of the dataset` and the number of data of `After Deleting the "True Duplicates"`. About `Diff Date Duplicates = 3`, between the number of data of `After Deleting the "True Duplicates"` and the number of data of `After Deleting the duplicate with the later date`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. In your sample value in the image, the number of data of `Here is a sample of the dataset` is 9. That of `After Deleting the "True Duplicates"` is 7. By this, I thought that `trueDuplicateCount` might become `9 - 7 = 2`. And, That of `After Deleting the duplicate with the later date` is 4. By this, I thought that `tdiffDateDuplicateCount` might become `7 - 4 = 3`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: See if the added image helps clear things up.

Comment: And yes. that makes sense now. That is correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. From the information, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the direction you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to modify it. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the inbuilt removeDuplicates method, which will remove duplicates in place. Use hash object to remove date duplicates afterwards:

#### Sample script:

```
function remDups(sheet) {
  let sh = sheet || SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let rg = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2);
  let initDataSz = rg.getNumRows();
  let newRg = rg.removeDuplicates();
  let newDataSz = newRg.getNumRows();
  //console.info({ initDataSz, newDataSz });
  let trueDups = initDataSz - newDataSz;
  let values = newRg.getValues();
  //newRg.copyTo(sh.getRange('C1'));
  newRg.clearContent();

  let out = Object.entries(
    values.reduce((obj, [date, color]) => {
      let oldDate = (obj[color] = obj[color] || Infinity);
      if (oldDate - date > 0) {
        obj[color] = date;
      }
      return obj;
    }, {})
  ).map(e => e.reverse());
  let falseDups = newDataSz - out.length;
  sh.getRange(2, 1, out.length, out[0].length).setValues(out);
  return [`${trueDups}`, `${falseDups}`];
}
```

#### Performance:

- ~2.6 seconds for 15000 rows on V8 engine

#### References:

- [Range#removeDuplicates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeduplicates)

Comment: Note: You need to [enable v8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime) , if not done already

Comment: I put in the code as is and it looks like you are outputting the columns in the next available columns. I would need the sheet cleared and then the columns inserted. Also.. it looks like it grabbed the header. Header would need to be removed and then put back in. Next thing I noticed were the counts that were placed at the bottom. These should be returned in an array. return [trueDups, dateDiffDups]

Comment: This is looking promising as it did seem to be slightly faster. I would imagine the larger the dataset the better this solution would be.

Comment: @Dan Just for reference,  How long did tanaike's and cooper's method take? I haven't tested `range#duplicates` against plain js.

Comment: Your script was about 5 seconds faster than tanaike's and cooper's was about 2 seconds slower than Tanaike.

Comment: @Dan 1.For 8k rows? 2. On v8 engine?

Comment: Yes, I will say that the script did not finish because my code was expecting the function to return an array. That may have skewed the results, in fact I can almost assure it. I'm trying to make the edits I commented earlier about but I feel like I've stumbled on another world. lol some of this stuff I've never seen before. haha

Comment: @Dan The changes are minor. You should be able to do it on your own. I've  edited my answer.(not tested)

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but first glance it looks like it will paste over the columns. should it be clearing the content of the sheet first?

Comment: Tested it. Didn't realize this before but the columns have switched positions. Also, falseDups wasn't what I was looking for. I was looking for the number of duplicates deleted after keeping the earliest date. Instead what was returned was the number of rows that were not duplicates.

Comment: You may be right. I must've grabbed one right before your edit. I've tested your latest and the switching of columns must've messed something up. Only returned 5 rows. I'm guessing it ran the duplicate check on the wrong column.

Comment: @Dan Could you test again on a new sheet? I edited my answer.

Comment: That worked. Now I can confirm that your script on my ~8K rows is almost 5 seconds faster than any other solution. Thank you for your help with this. I've selected yours as the answer. All of my conditions were met and speed was taken seriously as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function removeDuplicates(sh) {
  var v=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var u=[];
  var u0=[];
  var t=0;
  var t0=0;
  //var d=0;
  v.forEach(function(r,i){
    var found=false;
    //whole row match
    if(u.indexOf(r.join())==-1) {
      u.push(r.join());
    }else{
      sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
      t++;
      found=true;
    }
    if(!found) {
      //one column match setup for date
      var dts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(r[0]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd");
      if(u0.indexOf(dts)==-1) {
        u0.push(dts);
      }else{
        sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++)
        t0++;
      } 
    }
  });
  return [t,t0];
}
```

As you said this might be faster.  So give it a try.

```
function removeDuplicates(sh) {
  var v=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var u=[];
  var u0=[];
  var oA=[]
  var t=0;
  var t0=0;
  var d=0;
  v.forEach(function(r,i){
    var found=false;
    //whole row match
    if(u.indexOf(r.join())==-1) {
      u.push(r.join());
      oA.push(r);
    }else{
      //sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
      t++;
      found=true;
    }
    if(!found) {
      //one column match
      var dts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(r[0]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd");
      if(u0.indexOf(dts)==-1) {
        u0.push(dts);
        oA.push(r);
      }else{
        //sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++)
        t0++;
      } 
    }
  });
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
  return [t,t0];
}
```

Comment: I tested it and it successfully deletes the whole row duplicates but does not delete the duplicates based on one column.

Comment: The duration according to the executions log is less than one third of the time my original one was so there is progress there.

Comment: I see you are also deleting a row. Doesn't that add more time to the processing? I would think it would be faster to use the "found" variable to add to array if true and then clear the sheet and paste the array. Also.... keeping efficiency in mind. Wouldn't it also be faster to sort and then compare a row to the row above working your way up?

Comment: I was under the impression that you wanted to do both.  Perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: I do want to do both but when I ran this it deleted only the true duplicates. (whole row match). It did not delete the one column match (delete the older ones, keep the newest).

Comment: I guess your first column is a date that's probably why it's not working for that one.

Comment: Ok. Yes. the second is much much quicker but it's not working like intended. The count comes back as if all of the rows were duplicate except for the 5 unique dates. It should be delete the row if the value in column B is a duplicate AND the value in column A is older. (Keep only one... the youngest.)

Comment: Well if you want to share some data I'll debug it.

Comment: Are you saying that t and t0 are not different.  It there are only five unique dates then there should only be 5 rows left.

Comment: The dates in column A should only be referenced to determine which duplicates in column B should be deleted. I want to keep the one with the earliest date. What your script does is it treats column A like it's looking to delete duplicates from there.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to remove the duplicated values of date and color.
- You want to achieve the result, which is shown as the images, in your question.
- You want to reduce the process cost of your Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve values from the sheet.
2. Create an object for retrieving `trueDuplicateCount`.
3. Create an object for retrieving `diffDateDuplicateCount`.
4. Create an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
5. Put the values to the Spreadsheet.
6. Calculate `trueDuplicateCount` and `diffDateDuplicateCount`.

#### Sample script:

```
function removeDuplicates(sheet) {
  // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Retrieve values from the sheet.
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = data.shift(); // Remove the header row.

  // Create an object for retrieving trueDuplicateCount.
  var object1 = data.reduce(function(o, [a, b], i) {
    var key = b + "_" + a.getTime();
    o[key] = key in o ? o[key] + 1 : 1;
    return o;
  }, {});

  // Create an object for retrieving diffDateDuplicateCount.
  var object2 = Object.keys(object1).reduce(function(o, e) {
    var [c, d] = e.split("_");
    d = Number(d);
    o[c] = c in o ? (o[c] > d ? d : o[c]) : d;
    return o
  }, {});

  // Create an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  var ar = Object.keys(object2).map(function(e) {return [new Date(object2[e]), e]});
  ar.unshift(header);

  // Put the values to the Spreadsheet.
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);

  // Calculate trueDuplicateCount and diffDateDuplicateCount.
  var trueDuplicateCount = data.length - Object.keys(object1).length;
  var diffDateDuplicateCount = Object.keys(object1).length - Object.keys(object2).length;
  return [trueDuplicateCount, diffDateDuplicateCount];
}
```

- In above script, it supposes that the header row is existing in the 1st row. If you don't use the header row, please remove `data.shift()`.
- In this case, the result values are put from the 1st row like your script. So in this case, the header row is cleared. Please be careful this.

#### Note:

- In above script, the date values retrieved from the cells is used as the date object. Please be careful this.

### Added:

When v8 runtime can be used, above script can be written as follows.

```
function removeDuplicates_v8(sheet) {
  // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Retrieve values from the sheet.
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const header = data.shift(); // Remove the header row.

  // Create an object for retrieving trueDuplicateCount.
  const object1 = data.reduce((o, [a, b], i) => ({...o, [(b + "_" + a.getTime())]: true}), {});

  // Create an object for retrieving diffDateDuplicateCount and an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  const ar = Object.entries(Object.keys(object1).reduce((o, e) => {
    let [c, d] = e.split("_");
    d = Number(d);
    return {...o, [c]: new Date(c in o ? (o[c] > d ? d : o[c]) : d)};
  }, {})).map(([a, b]) => [b, a]);

  // Calculate trueDuplicateCount and diffDateDuplicateCount.
  const trueDuplicateCount = data.length - Object.keys(object1).length;
  const diffDateDuplicateCount = Object.keys(object1).length - ar.length;

  // Put the values to the Spreadsheet.
  sheet.clearContents();
  ar.unshift(header);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
  return [trueDuplicateCount, diffDateDuplicateCount];
}
```

Comment: Missing { after removeDuplicates(sheet)

Comment: That works perfectly! One thing though...the headers are gone. Could you add that back in. btw... this seemed to be very efficient. Fast.

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying. The script was modified for adding the header row. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Yes. That works. I see this script sorts it also. Nothing wrong with that but could you explain what part of the code does that?

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying. I have already added the explanation in the script. Can I ask you about your replying?

Comment: I added the sample script with the v8 runtime.

Comment: Did you make changes to the original one? I'm running it now and it doesn't seem to work. It's deleting a lot of the rows that are not duplicates. That's with both scripts. v8 and regular.

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying. I have not modified the original sample script. I just added one more sample script for V8. This can be seen at [the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60133841/revisions). Although I'm not sure about your current situation, I have to apologize that the script didn't work. In this case, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue?

Comment: I can copy unto an excel sheet as my work will not allow me to share. Where can I upload the excel sheet so you can copy unto google sheets?

Comment: @DanCue I would like to confirm your replying. Before 1 hour ago, you said `That works.`. But, in your current situation, you say `it doesn't seem to work`, even when I have not modified the script and you have not modified the Spreadsheet. I think that this is the important issue. When the V8 was enabled, in my environment, I could confirm that the 1st sample script worked. But if that is different from your environment, I think that this should be reported to Google side. How about this? And is my understanding of your replying correct?

Comment: I see what happened. Another script I ran from another answer switched the columns therefore altering the formatting and caused this error. I deleted the sheet and started from scratch. It works.

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying. I'm glad that the script works in your environment and that was not a bug for V8.

Comment: I'm going to pick up where I left off tomorrow. I just ran your v8 vs your original and the original ran faster. Not sure what's happening but I'll give it a fresh take tomorrow and pick an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm that your v8 runs 30x slower than your original for 15000x2 random rows on the same v8 engine.(1.9to2.5s for `removeDuplicates` and 56 to 62s for `removeDuplicates_v8`). Not sure why though.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. I think that it is interesting result. [This](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/3331e1e631d619abef8f32c4be14ba3a) is the benchmark of the loop cost for V8. In this case, it was found that when V8 is used, the cost of all methods of loop can be reduced by more than 90 %, when it is compared with the script without V8.

Comment: @TheMaster From this result and your result, I thought that when the script created by ES5 is run under V8, the process cost might be lower than that created by ES6. This is just my guess. I would like to actually experiment it. When you tested, how did you think about this?

Comment: @Tanaike In your experiment, it's only 90% reduction(2X). Here, the cost is around 300% increase(30X slower). I was able to pin point the cost to the code creating `object1`: `const object1 = data.reduce((o, [a, b], i) => ({...o, [(b + "_" + a.getTime())]: true}), {});`. `ar` creation/looping didn't take much time(almost negligible compared to `object1`).  My guess would be on `.getTime()` or the computed property creation: `[b+_]`.... need more testing to confirm.

Comment: Typo: 3000%. Testing again,  Maybe `in` is faster and destructuring with duplicate keys is slower.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. From your replying, when I checked my formulas again. I could notice that the cell of denominator was wrong. So I recalculated and updated the report. I think that your result, which has ES6 methods, is the reasonable value. Thank you, too. In this report, the scripts for ES5 were used for measuring the costs with and without V8. As the next step, I'm measuring the costs for the script with ES5 and ES6 under V8. When I got the result, I would like to report it.

Comment: @Tanaike I think this has nothing to do with ES5 or ES6 or V8. I think the problem is here: `({...o, [(b + "_" + a.getTime())]: true}), {});`. By creating a new object each time in the loop, process cost is exponentially higher. Here the engine needs to check for duplicate keys in `o` and create a new object each time. Comparatively, here: `o[key] = key in o ? o[key] + 1 : 1`, you're accessing only 1 key in memory. The problem isn't the syntax. It's the way each method operates. These are my conclusions in the test.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying and additional information. I would like to consider about it.